# Why is the type of a character column a list?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

Why is the type of the column created through map list? I would expect it to be a character column.  How can I convert it to a character column?

```
t <- mtcars %>% mutate(new_col=map(mpg, function(x) as.character(x)))
typeof(t$new_col)

> [1] "list"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map_chr()` instead of `map()`.

And you can just write

```
mtcars %>% mutate(new_col = map_chr(mpg, as.character))
```

Comment: Thank-you, I don't know how I missed this: ```map(), map_if() and map_at() always return a list. See the modify() family for versions that return an object of the same type as the input.``` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/map

Answer (score 3):

The result of `map` was a list. It's not generally wise to add lists to dataframes, but it can be done. The other common mistake is to add the result of `POSIXlt` to a dataframe. Again it can be done but subsequent operations may fail. You could have just used the function:

```
> t <- mtcars %>% mutate(new_col=as.character(mpg))
> typeof(t$new_col)
[1] "character"
```